# Angular Reutilizar una función en todos los componentes

Tags: angular, rxjs

Necesito reutilizar una función en todos los componentes que hace una llamada a varios servicios. Así que mi idea fue crear un servicio que a su vez llama a los demás servicios.

Componente

```
  this.resul = this.escribirService.escribir(param1,param2);
  console.log(this.resul);
```

Este es el servicio

```
 public escribir(
    param1: number,
    param2: string,
  ): boolean {

   let resultadoFinal:boolean = false;

    this.subscriptions.push(
   
      this.servicioL
        .getinfo1(param1, param2
        )
        .subscribe((resul1) => {
        resultadoFinal = resul1;
        
        }),

     
    this.servicioL
        .getinfo2(param1, param2    
        )
        .subscribe((resul2) => {
        resultadoFinal = resul2;
        
        }),
    return resultadoFinal;
  }
```

Claramente el retorno es incorrecto y me devuelve siempre false ya que el retorno de las subscripciones llegan más tarde. La cuestión es si me estoy equivocando al crear un servicio para reutilizar esta función. En el caso de que sea correcto hacer este servicio como hago para hacer que sea síncrono y que me devuelva los resultados de las subscripciones al componente?
Gracias

Comment: puedes hacer uso del await y async para que al consumir los servicios sea de manera sincrona y no asincrona. Y al ejecutar el servicio debes en ves de hacerlo con el subscribcion hacerlo con el toPromise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La verdad es que para hacer lo que quieres, debes hacer uso del await y async para el manejo sincrónico que deseas, pero hay que tener varias cosas en cuenta, ya que al hacer esto, en Angular la función que tienes retornando el tipo `boolean`, ya no va a ser así. Sino que retornaría una `Promise<boolean>`

De igual manera te dejaré el ejemplo de como tendrías que hacerlo.

```
// En tu Servicio
public async escribir(param1: number, param2: string): Promise<boolean> {

    let resultadoFinal = false;

    await this.servicioL.getinfo1(param1, param2).toPromise()
        .then(result => resultadoFinal = result);

    console.log('getinfo1', resultadoFinal);

    await this.servicioL.getinfo2(param1, param2).toPromise()
        .then(result => resultadoFinal = result);

    console.log('getinfo2', resultadoFinal);

    return resultadoFinal;
}
```

Ya que como te mencionaba, En la función `escribir`, el retorno ya no va a ser un `boolean` sino un `Promise<boolean>`, esta sería la forma como deberías sacar la información que te retorne el servicio.

```
// En tu Componente
this.escribirService.escribir(param1,param2).then(res => {
    this.resul = res;
    console.log(this.resul);
});
```

Otra opción de como obtener la información en tu componente es que a la función que tienes en tu Component, donde llamas la función escribir de tu servicios le hagas lo mismo que hicimos en el Service.

```
async pruebaComponent() { // Funcion en tu Component que llama al Service escribir
    await this.escribirService.escribir(param1,param2)
         .then(res => this.resul = res); // Ejecución del servicio escribir y asignación de la respuesta retornada a la variable result del Component
    console.log(this.resul); // Posterior a la ejecución del servicio se imprime el valor obtenido del servicio escribir
}
```

Esta ultima opción te la recomiendo si la función donde llamas al servicio escribir en tu Component no va a ralizar ningún retorno.

Puedes apoyarte del manejo del async y await en la siguiente página https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Espero te sirva.